# Como dejar una imagen fija sobre otra con css?

Tags: html5, bootstrap, css3, responsive

Mi pregunta es: tengo una imagen principal que la uso como fondo, bueno a la vez quiero poner varias imágenes sobre esta en diferentes posiciones con left y top, pero al hacerla responsiva estas imágenes que están dentro se pierden y se mueven mientras se achica la pantalla , lo que quiero hacer es que queden fijas, aquí les dejo mi código:

**HTML**

```
 <div class="contenedor-map">
        <img class="map" src="images/map.png">
        <div class="location1">
            <img class="img-fluid"  src="/images/locate1.png" >  
        </div> 
  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.contenedor-map{
         .map{
              position: relative;
              width: 100%;  
         }
         .location1{
            position: absolute;  
                img{ 
                    width: 5%;
                    top: 20%;
                    left: 16.5%;  
                }
         }
     }
```

Como se darán cuenta es un mapa donde irían localidades

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que la solución no es utilizar css y html, pero en base a la pregunta aquí está la respuesta

[![

```css
<style>
        .contenedor-map{
            position: relative;
        }
        .img-fluid{
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 1;
            width: 30px;            
        } 

    </style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Mapa</title>
    
</head>
<body>
    
    <div class="contenedor-map">
        <img class="map" id="mapa" src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/61zSkwAvlXL._AC_SX679_.jpg">
        <div class="location1">
            <img class="img-fluid" style="top: 100px; left: 150px;"  src="https://svgsilh.com/svg/1093169.svg" >  
        </div> 
        <div class="location2">
            <img class="img-fluid" style="top: 300px; left: 450px;"  src="https://svgsilh.com/svg/1093169.svg" >  
        </div> 
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```css
<style>
        .contenedor-map{
            position: relative;
        }
        .map{
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;
        }
        .img-fluid{
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 1;
            width: 30px;            
        }

    </style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Mapa</title>
    
</head>
<body>
    
    <div class="contenedor-map">
        <img class="map" src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/61zSkwAvlXL._AC_SX679_.jpg">
        <div class="location1">
            <img class="img-fluid" style="top: 100px; left: 150px;"  src="https://svgsilh.com/svg/1093169.svg" >  
        </div> 
        <div class="location2">
            <img class="img-fluid" style="top: 300px; left: 450px;"  src="https://svgsilh.com/svg/1093169.svg" >  
        </div> 
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8nNU.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8nNU.png)

La mejor solución es trabajar con vectores, porque si es responsivo entonces la ubicación no será correcta

Comment: Ahí probé pero lo que quiero hacer es que no se mueva la imagen de la location, y se sigue corriendo a medida que hago resposnive la pagina

Comment: Fue lo que te comente ***Creo que la solución no es utilizar css y html, pero en base a la pregunta aquí está la respuesta***

Comment: Los vectores tienen coordenadas por lo que siempre mantienen relación de aspecto, y puedes trabajar los puntos sobre la matriz de vectores, es la base de trabajar con mapas cada x,y es un localización, pero deberás formular la pregunta, ya que no es la solución a tu problema

Comment: claro , pero yo no quiero usar vector,

Comment: [aquí podras leer](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Adding_vector_graphics_to_the_Web)

Comment: [otra solución](https://sigdeletras.com/2021/desarrollo-web-de-visor-de-mapas-con-la-libreria-d3/)

Comment: si no quieres utilizar vectores, o librerías 3D, te recomiendo que trabajes con js, teniendo el tamaño del contenedor puedes calcular la relación de aspecto entre los valores padre e hijo y reubicar los elementos según su tamaño

Comment: bueno me funciono con los vectores,

Comment: muchas gracias.

Comment: te actualice la solución con css, pero te será complejo

Answer (score -1):

Trata de colocar la imagen principal como background del div, y las otras imagenes si como un elemento img.
Asegurate de colocar el div de la imagen principal con un tamaño específico y la imagen de fonto responsiva

Comment: Si, ya probe haciendo asi pero es lo mismo